# Icon inside a commun component fires error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons

I am trying to build a mobile app and to make my code clean, I decide to create commun components that I will use very ofter.

I want to create a Validation Button Component as follow :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Icon } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

/**
 * @export
 * @class ValidateButton
 * @extends {Component}
 */
export default class ValidateButton extends Component {
    /**
     * default props
     *
     * @static
     * @memberof ValidateButton
     */
    static defaultProps = {
      enabled: true,
    };

    /**
     * props validation
     *
     * @static
     * @memberof ValidateButton
     */
    static propTypes = {
      enabled: PropTypes.bool,
      clickHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

  /**
   * Render the validation button
   *
   * @returns {object}
   * @memberof ValidateButton
   */
    render() {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.footerBoldButton} onPress={this.props.enabled && this.props.clickHandler}>
          <Icon name="check" type="material" color="#FFF" iconStyle={styles.footerBoldButtonIcon} size={16} />
          <Text style={styles.footerBoldButtonText}>{this.props.label}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I call my component, an error is displayed :

```
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

And The weird thing, is that when I just delete the `Icon` element it works.

Does anyone have an explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why it does not work with `Icon` from `react-native` but I could make it work with `Icon` from `react-native-elements`